# magento 1.x When a full refund complete of the order need to generate custom mail

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Please any one help me on this point ,i want to generate a custom mail when get full refund of the order.Any idea on this please help me.i m new in this field..

Comment: you can use magento event obser for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a observer for event `sales_order_creditmemo_save_after`. In observer check for condition `$order->getTotalRefunded() == $order->getGrandTotal()`(Full refund condition). And then send email from here.

Comment: Thank you so much! i will try this method in my code. :)